# Ski Jumping Pairs?

Tags: game-identification

So I found this game on YouTube and, quite frankly, it's hilarious. It's a game about ski jumping pairs, in the vein of some sort of Olympics-esque competition with some seriously surreal moves. From the videos in the sidebar, I think this might be part of some kind of series? The creator of the YouTube implies that the game is Japanese in origin.

Warning, the video contains some NSFW language.

Comment: So this is a real thing. The video is hilarious nonetheless. I might have to try actually playing it now that I know it exists.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This 'game' is literally called [Ski Jumping Pairs](http://www.jump-pair.com/).  It was made by [Riichiro Mashima](https://twitter.com/Gibmelson), notable as the creator of arguably more hilarious [Japan World Cup 3](http://www.jra-jwc.jp/).